# My server sent to GPS Teltonika fm5300 acceptation byte 01 and after this didnt work

Tags: c#, gps

My server sent to GPS Teltonika fm5300 acceptation byte 01 after teltonika send IMEI, but it does not work....teltonika send IMEI again not data.

Here is my code:

```
class Server 
{ 
    byte[] responsebyte = new byte[] { 1 };

     private void Run()
    {
        running = true;
        ServerSocket.Listen(500);      
            while(running)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for GPS device...");
            Socket AcceptedData = ServerSocket.Accept();

            Console.WriteLine("GPS device connected " + AcceptedData.RemoteEndPoint + " " + DateTime.Now);
            data = new byte[AcceptedData.SendBufferSize];

            int j = AcceptedData.Receive(data);

            byte[] adata = new byte[j];
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                adata[i] = data[i];

            data = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved packet: "+ adata.Length);
            string dat = Encoding.Default.GetString(adata);
            Console.WriteLine(dat);

            if(AcceptedData.Connected == true) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sending response to " + AcceptedData.RemoteEndPoint +" " + DateTime.Now + " Data size: " + responsebyte.Length );


                AcceptedData.Send(responsebyte);
                Console.WriteLine("Response sent..." + AcceptedData.RemoteEndPoint);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not send response to gps device");                    
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");

            AcceptedData.Disconnect(true);                
        }
        ServerSocket.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ForceMagic do you have any idea?

Comment: Not really, I was just fixing the formatting. However, if you could add more info about the problem, I'm not sure to fully understand. What's the acceptation byte? Is it that which doesn't work or it's that you don't receive anything back? Use the edit link button to add more info to your question, it will help others get i context and reply you faster :) (Welcome on SO btw, this is a good first post! There's a nice tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour if you want to learn more about StackOverflow) :)

Comment: @ForceMagic ok....i explain you. gps device send IMEI number to server, and after this, server must send a 1 byte( as binary packet, but this i dont know how to do it), if server can accept next gps data send to device 01 or 00 if not

Answer (score 0):

```
if (imei == "xyz")
{
    string Password = "01";
    byte[] PasswordBytes = Password.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
    stream.Write(PasswordBytes, 0, PasswordBytes.Length);
    Library.WriteErrorLog("Password Sent for- " + StrInput) ;}
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation.